# Ocultar versão do Tomcat nas páginas de erro

Tags: segurança, servidor, tomcat

Tenho uma `API Rest` rodando em um servidor `Tomcat`. Se tento acessar diretamente a API e acontece algum erro a página de erros do `Tomcat` é exibida:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Reparem que no final se encontra o seguinte trecho: **Apache Tomcat/8.0.30**.

Diante da situação tenho algumas questões:

- Seria uma falha de segurança deixar a versão exposta dessa forma?
- Como faço pra ocultar essa versão no Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em si, não é uma falha de segurança, mas ainda é uma boa ideia esconder essa informação. Pois caso no futuro se venha a descobrir vulnerabilidades nessa versão específica, e seu serviço não seja atualizado para uma versão mais segura do Tomcat (o que idealmente não deveria ocorrer, mas na prática pode, por diversos motivos), então "anunciar pro mundo" que você está rodando um serviço vulnerável facilitaria o trabalho de quaisquer atacantes que estiverem visando seu servidor.

Para ocultar essa informação, pode-se seguir o procedimento descrito [nessa página](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/08/hide-tomcat-version-number/) ou alternativamente [aquele descrito no site da OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Securing_tomcat#Common) (inclui outras sugestões para manter sua instância segura, vale a pena ler):

1. Encontre o arquivo `catalina.jar` (está dentro da pasta especificada como `CATALINA_HOME`, na subpasta `server\lib`) e extraia do mesmo o arquivo

   ```
   org/apache/catalina/util/ServerInfo.properties
   ```
2. Atualize esse arquivo substituindo (ou acrescentando) o `server.info` com alguma string de sua escolha. Exemplo:

   ```
   server.info=Apache Tomcat
   ```
3. Das duas uma:

   - Coloque o arquivo atualizado de volta no jar (pode quebrar algumas aplicações, como o Lambda Probe); ou:
   - Crie a estrutura de pastas `lib\org\apache\catalina\util` dentro de `CATALINA_HOME` e coloque a versão modificada do `ServerInfo.properties` lá.
4. Reinicie o Tomcat.

Isso deve fazer com que as mensagens de erro exibam a string que você escolheu (no exemplo acima, `Apache Tomcat`) em vez daquela que informa o número de versão.

Comment: Excelente!!!!!!

Comment: Muito obrigado @mgibsonbr funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Excelente!!! Fiz aqui e deu super certo!! Valeu!! Regina Deboni